# Well-founded orders and sums

Tags: reference-request, order-theory, ordinals

I am looking for a reference on well-founded ordered sets, that would mention the following notions and results:

$\\$

**a)** Consider a well-ordered set $(I,<)$ and a family $(X_i,<_i)$ of well-founded ordered sets. The sum $\sum \limits_{i \in I} X_i$ of the family is the set $\bigcup  \limits_{i \in I} X_i \times \{i\}$ ordered by $(x,i)<(y,j)$ if $i<j$ or $i=j$ and $x<_iy$.

**b)** Given a well-founded ordered set $(X,<)$ and $x \in X$, the rank of $x$ is the ordinal $r(x)=\sup  \{r(y)+1 : \ y<x\}$ and the rank of $X$ is the supremum of $r(X)$.

**c)** For ordinals $\alpha,\beta$, the ordinal $\alpha +\beta$ is the order type of $\sum \limits_{i \in I} X_i$ where $I=2$ and $(X_0,X_1)=(\alpha,\beta)$. The ordinal $\alpha \beta$ is the order type of $\sum \limits_{i \in I} X_i$ where $I=\beta$ and $X_i=\alpha$ for all $i\in \beta$.

**d)** The rank of $\sum \limits_{i \in I} X_i$ is the order type of $\sum \limits_{i \in I} r(X_i)$.

---

Does someone know a reference with all of that or at least **a)**, **b)** and **d)**?

Comment: Isn't (a) just the general definition of summation of orders?

Comment: @AsafKaragila Yes it is. In the case of well-founded orders (and well-founded index set) it remains well-founded.

Comment: I suspect that these things will be in (most? a?) book about BQOs or something like that.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I'll look around in this sector then. I had not realized it, but the orderings I am working with are well-quasi-orderings, so Noetherian orderings.